# CakePHP and DefaultPasswordHasher syntax error

Tags: cakephp-3.0, password-encryption

I have no clue why but for the line

`use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;`

I'm getting an error

`Error: syntax error, unexpected '?'`

[image]

and full code of user.php

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

/**
 * User Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $modified
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Bookmark[] $bookmarks
 */
class User extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ];

    /**
     * Fields that are excluded from JSON versions of the entity.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($value){

    $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher->hash($value);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? I'm using latest CakePHP

Comment: can you please give me the error message screen shot?

Comment: @Faisal OP updated with the screenshot

Comment: Have you look at `User` entity class ?

Comment: go to that file line no 5. hope you have a clue regarding the error message.

Comment: if you dont understand then please give us that file screen shot. i will help you to solve this issue?

Comment: The line #5 from that file is `use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;`

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the shown line is the cause of that error. When posting such questions, please make sure that you show enough code so that the problem is reproducable for others, and don't forget to elaborate about the context, like your CakePHP and PHP version, which could have influence on syntax related problems.

Comment: @ndm code from `user.php` was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this one. Please update your CakePHP project with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), it will update all dependency if you miss something.

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{

    // Make all fields mass assignable except for primary key field "id".
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ];

    // ...

    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Also please read this doc [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/3863). Hope it should be help you to solve this issue.

Comment: It looks like I had something missing on cakePHP installation. Now almost all works fine except on `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl())` I'm getting an error message `A route matching "/" could not be found.` and `Router::scope` for `'/'` has `$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class)`

Answer (score 0):

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
/**
 * User Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $role
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $modified
 */
class User extends Entity
{

```
/**
 * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
 *
 * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
 * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
 * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
    'id' => false
];

/**
 * Fields that are excluded from JSON versions of the entity.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_hidden = [
    'password'
];

protected function _setPassword($password) {
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

}